# How to execute linux command Kernel.system method correctly on rails (production env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell

I exucute command line syntax in my rails application (development env) `Kernel.system('sudo chmod 777 /aaa/bbb')` and working correctly, and `return true`

but I don't know when I execute on production (application) it does'nt work `return false`,

but strangely, I run on rails console (production) it working correctly, `return true`.

anyone know, what's wrong with this ?

Thanks

Comment: `sudo <something>` will execute `<something>` as the su (Super User), You need a password for that. When you test on your local dev env, are you logged as Root on your computer? When you run Rails console on the production mode, are you using the Super User rôle ?

Comment: but why on rails console it working (I ran from application root), so it same environtment right ? or it different ?

Comment: You didn't answer any of my previous questions, but you asked a new one. I can't help you if you don't answer my previous questions. This is why I've asked them. To try to find a solution for you, not to get another question. I repeat: 1): When you run your `rails console` on the production server, are you logged as `root`? 2): Same question when you run this command on your Development env. If yes, then it means your Rails application is launched as a regular user and it can't run a `sudo <something>`.

Comment: Also, making a `chmod 777 /path/to/somewhere` on a production server is a bad idea. at least do a `chmod 754 /path/` (equivalent to Owner: rwx, Group: rw-, Other: r--). Or eventually `chmod 774 /path/` (gives execution permission to the Group)

Comment: ah ok, sorry. 1. on production, yes logged on as root. 2. yes, so on development. as root

Comment: yeah, thanks MrYoshiji for your responses.

Comment: So your Application is running as a regular user (not a Super User). You have to find an other way to change the chmod (I don't recommend you to run your Rails app as Root (=Super User) because it means it could do **everything** on your server (imagine a user is able to exec a command on your server, what is he does `rm -rf /` with your App running as Root? It would erase everything on your server.